# How to find pattern in sequential data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

I have multiple sequential data that lead up to an event. All I want to do if find the equivalent sequential data or a pattern that leads to the event. The data is also multivariate so I want to consider multiple features rather than just a column. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that an event corresponds to exactly one input sequence (i.e. you must have a "full" sequence for the event to appear), or that that an event may appear at any point of the sequence?

Comment: There is a sequence of inputs that result in an event to occur but I am focusing on the last 20 inputs before the event occurs because the size of the input space can be of varying size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure but it looks like [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) might be what you need:

- Sequences of varying length
- Supervised: you would need to train a model with a sample of sequences annotated with a label at every step (not sure that this is your use case?)
- Can handle any number of features

[Conditional Random Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) is the state of the art method, there are many libraries
available.